# AWS - Associate EC2 with SSM to enable ssm.client.send_command

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, cloud, boto3, aws-ssm

I'd like to run a series of bash commands through boto3 on a newly launched instance.

From some research it appears that associating this new instance with SSM is required to achieve this.

*Are there any clear mistakes or missed steps below? Also are there better approaches to achieve the stated goal?*

### Step 1 - Get clients and resources

```
import boto3

ec2c = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2r = boto3.resource('ec2')
ssmc = boto3.client('ssm')
```

### Step 2 - Create and wait for instance

```
instances = ec2r.create_instances(
    ImageId = 'ami-####',
    InstanceType = 't2.micro',
    MinCount = 1,
    MaxCount = 1,
    SecurityGroupIds = ['sg-####'])

instance_ids = [i.id for i in instances]
instance = instances[0]

instance.wait_until_running()
```

### Step 3 - Associate instance with IAM profile

***"RoleName" has the `AmazonEC2RoleforSSM` policy attached to it***

```
res = ec2c.associate_iam_instance_profile(
    IamInstanceProfile={
        'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::###:instance-profile/RoleName',
        'Name': 'RoleName'
    },
    InstanceId = instance.id
)
```

### Step 4 - Check for associations

```
print(ssmc.describe_instance_information()['InstanceInformationList'])

> []
```

**(I think this empty list is why the next step is failing)**

### Step 5 - Run commands

```
resp = ssmc.send_command(
    DocumentName = "AWS-RunShellScript",
    Parameters = {'commands': [mkdir app]},
    InstanceIds = instance_ids
)

> botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred ...
> ... (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation:
```

Comment: SSM requires an agent running on the instance. Is your instance running the agent? If you only need the commands to run once when you launch the instance, you should be using a user-data script. Otherwise, you can also use ssh, or any kind of orchestration system like mcollective or rundeck.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the InvalidInstanceId exception because the ssm agent is not running on your instance.